# SQL Server Import Wizard Date Conversion Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to import a csv file to SQL Server but keep getting an error like this

```
The data conversion for column "Date" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

My Date values look like this:

```
1/16/2017 0:00
```

And I tried the different datetime options in the advanced setting but it's still not working.

Comment: You have a time portion in there as well. A `date` doesn't contain a time, only a date. You need to be very explicit with your data when dealing with SSIS; it won't let you import a value that looks like a date and time value into a `date` column unless you explicitly tell it to convert the value. I also, however, recommend not using an unambigious date format; to me that date says 01 16th Month 2017, and there are 16 months in the year. The only unambiguous formats, in SQL Server, are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`.

Comment: So in advanced setting, which data type should I choose for this type of value? I wish I could but I can't make direct changes on the raw data.

Comment: if you have a date and time value, use a `datetime`/`datetime2`